# JSDoc for TCG game entity configuration

Tags: javascript, beginner, game

The Cardshifter team has been working at "translating" a very complex Java class into JavaScript, to make it more accessible to somebody who would want to fork the game and make their own modification, which is an objective that's been close to our hearts since the very beginning (for the game to be very *"moddable"*).

I started writing JSDoc into what we have adapted to JS so far. I have never written JSDoc before, hence I am seeking advice for improvement. The documentation is purposefully worded to be read and understood by a [beginner](/questions/tagged/beginner) who is just starting on the project. My main concerns:

- Is it clear?
- Is it redundant/too much?
- Is my use of `@implements` and `@param` good?

Here is the original [PhrancisGame.java](https://github.com/Cardshifter/Cardshifter/blob/95cb21556f5948b45a75a20e3b1651529fa54d32/cardshifter-core/src/main/java/net/zomis/cardshifter/ecs/usage/PhrancisGame.java) class.

Here is the documentation and code so far:

```
/**
 * Replicates the logic located in PhrancisGame.java
 * This module is to set up all the core game components required to start a game
 * Location of original Java file:
 *   cardshifter-core/src/main/java/net/zomis/cardshifter/ecs/usage/PhrancisGame.java 
 * @module PhrancisGame
 */

/** Card zones and owners */
var ZoneComponent = Java.type("com.cardshifter.modapi.cards.ZoneComponent");
/** Players & win/lose logic */
var PlayerComponent = Java.type("com.cardshifter.modapi.base.PlayerComponent");
/** Build decks using min/max size and cards */
var DeckConfigFactory = Java.type("net.zomis.cardshifter.ecs.config.DeckConfigFactory");
/** Potential configurations for players/entities. Primarily stores DeckConfigs */
var ConfigComponent = Java.type("net.zomis.cardshifter.ecs.config.ConfigComponent");
/** 
 * Enum that represents various player resources:
 * MAX_HEALTH, SNIPER, DOUBLE_ATTACK, TAUNT, DENY_COUNTERATTACK, HEALTH, MANA, MANA_MAX, SCRAP, 
 * ATTACK, MANA_COST, SCRAP_COST, ENCHANTMENTS_ACTIVE, SICKNESS, ATTACK_AVAILABLE
 * @implements ECSResource
*/
var PhrancisResources = Java.type("net.zomis.cardshifter.ecs.usage.PhrancisGame.PhrancisResources");
/**
 * Stores resources for entities
 * @implements CopyableComponent
 */
var ECSResourceMap = Java.type("com.cardshifter.modapi.resources.ECSResourceMap");
/**
 * Store attributes for entities
 * @implements CopyableComponent
 */
var ECSAttributeMap = Java.type("com.cardshifter.modapi.attributes.ECSAttributeMap");
/**
 * Core class for starting a Cardshifter game
 * @implements ECSMod
 */
var baseMod = Java.type("net.zomis.cardshifter.ecs.usage.PhrancisGame");
/** Card attributes */
var Attributes = Java.type("com.cardshifter.modapi.attributes.Attributes");

/**
 * Declare game configuration
 * @param {Object} game - Game configuration data
 */
function declareConfiguration(game) {
    var neutral = game.newEntity();
    /**
     * @param {Object} owner - Owner of the ZoneComponent.
     * @param {string} name - Name of the ZoneComponent.
     */
    var zone = new ZoneComponent(neutral, "Cards");
    neutral.addComponent(zone);
    addCards(zone);

    /** Parameters related to DeckConfigFactory */
    var maxCardsPerType = 3;
    var minSize = 30;
    var maxSize = 30;

    /**
     * Create playerComponent 0 & 1, i.e., Player1 & Player2
     * Config a deck for each player
     */
    for (var i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
        /**
         * @param {Object} newEntity() - New game entity.
         */
        var entity = game.newEntity();
        /**
         * @param {int} index - Index of the playerComponent.
         * @param {string} name - Name of the playerComponent.
         */
        var playerComponent = new PlayerComponent(i, "Player" + (i+1));
        /**
         * @param {Object} playerComponent - Add the playerComponent to the game entity.
         */
        entity.addComponent(playerComponent);
        /**
         * @param {int} minSize - Minimum number of cards per deck.
         * @param {int} maxSize - Maximum number of cards per deck.
         * @param {Object} getCards() - Card ownership from ZoneComponent class.
         * @param {int} maxCardsPerType - Maximum card of each type per deck.
         */
        var config = DeckConfigFactory.create(minSize, maxSize, zone.getCards(), maxCardsPerType);
        /**
         * @param {Object} ConfigComponent() - Configuration for player entities.
         */
        entity.addComponent(new ConfigComponent().addConfig("Deck", config));
    }
}

/**
 * @params {Object} zone - Zone to which to add cards & attributes to.
 */

function addCards(zone) {
    var entity = zone.getOwner().getGame().newEntity();
    /**
     * @param {Object} entity - Entity to which resources are being mapped.
    */
    ECSResourceMap.createFor(entity)
        .set(PhrancisResources.HEALTH, 5)
        .set(PhrancisResources.MAX_HEALTH, 5)
        .set(PhrancisResources.ATTACK, 1)
        .set(PhrancisResources.SCRAP, 3)
        .set(PhrancisResources.MANA_COST, 2)
        .set(PhrancisResources.SICKNESS, 1)
        .set(PhrancisResources.TAUNT, 1)
        .set(PhrancisResources.ATTACK_AVAILABLE, 1);
    /**
     * @param {Object} entity - Entity to which attributes are being mapped.
     * @param {string} name - Name of the attribute.
     */
    ECSAttributeMap.createFor(entity).set(Attributes.NAME, "Testing Thing");
    var mod = new baseMod();
    /**
     * @param {string} EffectComponent - Determine the effect/creature type of the entity.
     *   Currently available: "Mech", "Bio"
     */
    entity.apply(mod.creature("Mech"));
    /**
     * @param {Object} entity - Entity to add to bottom of zone
     */
    zone.addOnBottom(entity);
    return entity;
}
/**
 * @param {Object} game - Game configuration.
 */
function setupGame(game) {

}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Is it clear?

No. It would be easier to read with more vertical spacing (blank lines),
for example after each `/** ... */` + variable.

> Is it redundant/too much?

Yes.
I don't know of a precedent of documenting *variables*. 
For example:

> ```
> /**
>  * @param {Object} owner - Owner of the ZoneComponent.
>  * @param {string} name - Name of the ZoneComponent.
>  */
> var zone = new ZoneComponent(neutral, "Cards");
> ```

The documentation of the `ZoneComponent` constructor should be written where it's defined, not here where you use it.

I think you should delete most of the documentation in the posted code,
keeping only:

- the documentation at the top of the file
- the documentation of the functions you defined yourself (`declareConfiguration`, `addCards`, ...)

> Is my use of `@implements` and `@param` good?

The typical use of `@implements` is to mark classes that implement some interface. But you marked instances. 
Instances don't implement interfaces, they use them.

The use of `@param` is good.

Comment: Thanks janos for the advice, I thought it looked bloated, glad to hear it from someone more experienced